# How does DataBound works on Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm displaying at least 5 different types of notes, i.e. client note, system note, project note, contact note, and so forth using the same **KendoGrid**. Depending on the type of note I want to edit, I'll need to disable some of the dropdownlist or texbox controls.

In asp.net gridview control, I'd plug my logic inside the OnDataBound method, look for the row that's being edited, and finally search for controls that I want to interact with.

I've noticed that KendoGrid also has a **dataBound** event like this

```
dataBound: function (e) {
   //...                
}
```

Is it possible to know the access the row that is being edited? If so, is it also possible to access the underlining data?

Maybe there is also a event such as **onEditing**.

Thank for helping.

Comment: Are you using the kendo grid via JavaScript or server side HtmlHelper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [edit event for KendoUI grid](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit). I believe this is what you are looking for.